# onPostExecute causing application to crash

Tags: android

Below is my `onPostExecute` method.  When my `AsyncTask` fires it does everything that it suppose to do but when it tries to execute my `onPostExecute` my application crashes and I get this message in my `logcat`

```
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at com.testapp1.ListView$LoadAllData.onPostExecute(ListView.java:193)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at com.testapp1.ListView$LoadAllData.onPostExecute(ListView.java:1)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-14 22:45:22.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1141):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my `onPostExecute` method

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {

        if(file_URL.equals("0")) { 
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ListView.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        }else{

        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                    R.layout.listelements,
                    new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT }, new int[] {
                    R.id.Subject,});

            setListAdapter(adapter);                

        }}}
```

May I please have somebody help with this issue that I have.

Comment: Well, in your log, the error is NullPointerException.  Something you are calling/trying to access isn't there.  What is line 193?  Also, I think you're gonna need braces around `pDialog.dismiss();` following your if statement.

Comment: @MarcinGawel line 193 is `if(file_URL.equals("0")) {`

Comment: @nexus_2006 line 193 is `if(file_URL.equals("0")) {`

Comment: If so make sure that doInBackground never return null, because fileUrl is null at that point causing the NullPointerException, or simply check the nullity like: `if(file_URL!=null && file_URL.equals("0"))`

Comment: @gomino I think he wan't to find out when there's no URL so he should check `== null`. See my anwer below.

Comment: not sure! in order to be equal to '0' file_URL should not be null, but it's hard to tell what he wants to do with it because he is never using file_URL inside the condition

Comment: @gomino  `if(file_URL!=null && file_URL.equals("0"))` fixed my problem thank you very much!!

Comment: let me turn my comment into an anwser so that you can mark the post as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check file_URL :`if(file_URL!=null && file_URL.equals("0"))`

Comment: No prob, FYI you can also use TextUtils.isEmpty(file_URL) in order to check a String for nullity and emptyness at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line

`if(file_URL.equals("0")) {`

to

`if(file_URL == null || file_URL.equals("0")) {`

Comment: If the issue is NPE on file_URL, wouldn't that still cause it as it has to run both conditions anyway?

Comment: `||` is orelse so the second part won't be executed if the first one is true.

Comment: Thank you very much!! for trying to assist me with my issue but @gomino comment solved my problem.

Comment: I'm happy to hear your problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`if(file_URL.equals("0"))` is line 193, so this is where the NPE occurs. What's happening here is that `file_URL` itself is null, and you're running a method off a null item - hence the issue.

So to fix this, wrap it up:

```
if(file_URL != null){
  // Your code
}
```