# onPostExecute not executing my method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my application I have my `onPostExecute` to carry out a certain method if my web service doesn't return any data. I had a problem like this in one of my old questions which you can see right here [onPostExecute causing application to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807228/onpostexecute-causing-application-to-crash) Now if you read my question in that link then you would know that when my application returned the value `"0"` it crashed.  But now my problem is different, Whenever my web service does return count `"0"` my application displays a blank layout instead of executing the method I want it to execute.  Can somebody take a long at my  `onPostExecute` and assist me with this problem.

```
               final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
 final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
 final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
 final String TAG_QUESTION = "question";
 final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
 final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
 final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
 final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    
 final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "content";      
 final String TAG_QUERY = "query";
 final String TAG_COUNT = "count";
 ProgressDialog pDialog;
 LoadAllData mTask;
```

....

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

```
            pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){ 
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) { 
                    mTask.cancel(true); 
                    finish(); 
            } 
       }); 

            try {
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://example.com";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {

                    JSONArray questions = json.getJSONObject("all").getJSONArray("questions");

                    for(int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject question = questions.getJSONObject(i);


                    String Subject = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                    String ChosenAnswer = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                    String Content = question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                           HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                           map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                           map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT, Content);
                           map.put(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER, ChosenAnswer);

                           questionList.add(map);

                }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

                return null;       

    }



@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {

        if(file_URL!=null && file_URL.equals("0")) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ListView.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();

        } else {

            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) 
                pDialog.dismiss();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                    R.layout.listelements,
                    new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT }, new int[] {
                    R.id.Subject,});

            setListAdapter(adapter);                

        }
    }
```

This is what the data looks like when it returns `count "0"`

```
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882): {
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882): "all" : {
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882):     "count" : 0,
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882):     "questions" : [     ]
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882):     }
09-02 00:25:55.466: D/JSON String(882): }
```

This what the data looks like when it does return data or a valid `count`

```
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891): {
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891): "all" :    {
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):    "count" : 25,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):    "questions" : [     {   
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Id" : "20100728112033AAb4hTA",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Subject" : "What is the oldest a bitch can more or less safely breed?",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Content" : "Don't worry I'm not going to breed - both my bitches are getting neutered in the next year, as is my dog! Just that me and a friend were talking about it after talking to the man who gave me Misty (my border collie) who said she could still breed at 7 - I thought the oldest was 5?\n",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Date" : "2010-07-28 18:20:33",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Timestamp" : "1280341233",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Link" : "http://answers.yahoo.com/question/?qid=20100728112033AAb4hTA",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "Type" : "Answered",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "CategoryId" : 396546021,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "CategoryName" : "Dogs",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "UserId" : "cP16Ctgxaa",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "UserNick" : "Kiko",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "UserPhotoURL" : "http://l.yimg.com/dg/users/1t1USxJpxAAEBQOGZjBMW0-5Wp_EG.medium.jpg",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "NumAnswers" : 8,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "NumComments" : 0,
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswer" : "You just \"imagined\" that ,dear...not \"thought\". & your imagination is WRONG.\r\n\r\n9 or even 10,for a healthy TOP-PRODUCING bitc-h.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n*&* bitches are SPAYED & dogs are CASTRATED......big scary correct ADULT words.",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswererId" : "clN6YITvaa",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswererNick" : "Debunker",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswerTimestamp" : "1280317077",
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):            "ChosenAnswerAwardTimestamp" : "1280835336"
08-30 00:36:07.917: D/JSON String(1891):        },      {
```

The reason why the screen is blank because it is trying populate my listview but the count is zero so that is why it is blank. I just need to know why it wont execute `if(file_URL!=null && file_URL.equals("0")) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(ListView.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();` when it does return `count "0"`

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever my web service does return count "0" my application displays a blank layout instead of executing the method I want it to execute.

If it returns `0` then the only code that will run is

```
    pDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(ListView.this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
```

From what I see, you aren't calling a method other than dismissing your `ProgressDialog`, showing a `Toast`, then finishing your `Activity`.

Comment: Im sorry I explained my question the wrong way... In my older question that is in the link, when ever my web service DOESNT return count `"0"` it caused my application to crash. That was when I was suggest to use `if(file_URL!=null && file_URL.equals("0"))` to check if the web service returns `0` so my application doesn't crash if the web service doesn't return `0`. But when my web service DOES return `0` it displays the blank screen

Comment: No, that's how I read it. What I'm saying is I don't know what you want to happen if it *does* `return "0"`. You are calling `finish();` so it will close this `Activity`.

Comment: But when I try `if(file_URL == null || file_URL.equals("0"))` my toast message displays and it finishes the activity but when the web services doesn't return `0` it stills finishes the activity

Comment: i know you told me this code was suppose to work but can you please take a look at my updated `doInBackGround` method to see if anything could be causing the blank screen to appear instead of finishing the activity. If you dont see anything wrong, i would be just be happy if you give it a second look

Comment: I'm still not sure what's going on but it wouldn't be from your `doInBackground()` since it doesn't run on the `UI Thread`. Is `getIntent();` returning anything there? I wouldn't think it would without a `Context`

Comment: I am passing a string into my `doInBackGround` method that is why I have `getIntent` there

Comment: That's not how you get the `String`. The variable in your method header is the `String` passed in. Here it is `args`

Comment: im taking the string from an edit text from another activity and passing it in

Comment: Pass it from the `Activity` you are in to `AsyncTask` through `execute()` or make it a member variable and access it that way